# Referencing namespace from another class

Tags: c++, visual-c++, namespaces

I have a class called GeoSheet;

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "GeoSheet.h"

namespace A {
    int isClosable; 
    double x; 
}

void CGeoSheet::OnOK()  
{
    A::isClosable = 0;
    CPropertySheet::OnClose();
}
```

I want to access and modify variable 'isClosable' from another file called test.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "test.h"
#include "GeoSheet.h"

void main(){
    //access variable
}
```

How do I achieve this. I want to access the variable without having to instantiate an instance of GeoSheet.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`isClosable` doesn't belong to any class; it is just a global variable put in the namespace. You can use it in main the same way you've used it inside the class method, there is no difference.

Comment: If I just use A::isClosable in main() I get the following errors; error C2653: 'A' : is not a class or namespace name, 'isClosable' : undeclared identifier

Comment: you need to include header containing this namespace and, hence, variable declaration.

Comment: I'm using #include "GeoSheet.h", should I use something else?

Comment: you should include file containing this: `namespace A {
    int isClosable; 
    double x; 
}`

Comment: @Madz I think what you need is not to access `isClosable`, but a more solid understanding of the C++ language. It looks like you are doing cargo cult programming while barely understanding the C++ syntax.